# hive's Storage-based Authorization and Standard-Based Authorization

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I want to configure hive with Standard-Based Authorization and Storage-based Authorization.In hortonworks document said:
**hive.server2.enable.doAs**

> Must be set to FALSE for SQL standard-based
>       authorization.

and then said :

> Must be set to true for storage-based access.

I want the both config,what do i configure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, using both is not an option, so you'll have to choose.

The good news is that the decision is easy, because what you called "Standard-Based Authorization", or DefaultHiveMetastoreAuthorizationProvider is pretty much useless. It relies on a grant/revoke model in the metastore, and in practice, users can just grant themselves access whenever they want.

For any *actual* security, you must use **storage based authorization**.

Sources:

1. https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/53797/hive-metastore-authorization.html
2. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Storage+Based+Authorization+in+the+Metastore+Server